# Use proxy settings of the local machine in httpclient without requiring a password

Tags: c#, proxy, dotnet-httpclient

When I installed google chrome, it automatically uses my PC's proxy settings and requests work fine.

When I create a `HttpClient` I can only get the proxy to work if I provide my domain\username and password.

Is there a way to get it to use the same global proxy settings as my PC so I don't need to input my password?

Comment: Is this an app or a web app? What do you have in your web/app config?

Comment: Have You tried to look for it at all? I have seen several questions on this topic..

Comment: I did try to look for it, I see that link above answers it so feel free to mark as duplicate. I read several questions on how to supply a username and password, couldn't find one that explained how to do it without specifying hence I put it explicitly into the question. Many thanks.

Comment: If you use `WebClient` it as a `.UseDefaultProxy()` method for this reason.